# Cannot cast ListType[tuple(float64 x 2)] to list(tuple(float64 x 2)) in numba

Tags: numba

Hello I am trying to use typed List in numba v46.0

```
>>> from numba.typed import List
>>> from numba import types
>>> mylist = List.empty_list(item_type=types.Tuple((types.f8, types.f8)))
>>> mylist2 = List.empty_list(item_type=types.List(dtype=types.Tuple((types.f8, types.f8))))
>>> mylist2.append(mylist)
```

but I got the following error, I am wondering how to fix it?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/typed/typedlist.py",
>   line 223, in append
>       _append(self, item)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line
>   401, in _compile_for_args
>       error_rewrite(e, 'typing')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line
>   344, in error_rewrite
>       reraise(type(e), e, None)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/six.py", line 668, in
>   reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb) numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend) Internal error at
>   . Failed in
>   nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend) Cannot cast
>   ListType[tuple(float64 x 2)] to list(tuple(float64 x 2)): %".24" =
>   load {i8*, i8*}, {i8*, i8*}* %"item"
>
> File
>   "../../usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/listobject.py",
>   line 434:
>       def impl(l, item):
>           casteditem = _cast(item, itemty)

Answer (score 1):

the following should work

```
mylist2 = List.empty_list(item_type=types.ListType(itemty=types.Tuple((types.f8, types.f8))))
```